# Can I read and write file in one line with Python?

Tags: python, file, file-io

with ruby I can

```
File.open('yyy.mp4', 'w') { |f| f.write(File.read('xxx.mp4')}
```

Can I do this using Python ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
with open('yyy.mp4', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(open('xxx.mp4', 'rb').read())
```

Note the binary mode flag there (`b`), since you are copying over `mp4` contents, you don't want python to reinterpret newlines for you.

That'll take a lot of memory if `xxx.mp4` is large. Take a look at the [`shutil.copyfile` function](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) for a more memory-efficient option:

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfile('xxx.mp4', 'yyy.mp4')
```

Comment: <joke> You might want to move `f.write` onto the same like as `with open(...)` just so that it is all "on the same line" :^)  </joke>

Comment: Ick. Don't make me feed you a print-out of PEP-8 now. Printed in a 100pt font. On A3 paper. Single-sided too!

Comment: But yyy.mp4 is not exist, ruby can create it before write

Comment: @why: Opening a file for writing creates it.

Comment: Wouldnt' it be a little cleaner to use `with open('yyy.txt', 'wb') as f, open('xxx.txt', 'rb') as g:` then `f.write(g.read())`?

Comment: @martineau: Sure, but I was echoing the ruby code exactly; it uses an anonymous `File.read` in the same manner.

Comment: +1 for `shutil.copyfile`. Why would you open a file only to write it right back out without touching its contents? Perhaps it's purely for the sake of example, but still.

Comment: That is not one line.

Answer (score 2):

Python is not about writing ugly one-liner code.

Check the documentation of the shutil module - in particular the copyfile() method.

http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy a file, do not manually read then write bytes, use file copy functions which are generally much better and efficient for a number of reasons in this simple case.

If you want a true one-liner, you can replace line-breaks by semi-colons :

```py
import shutil; shutil.copyfile("xxx.mp4","yyy.mp4")
```

**Avoid this!** I did that once to speed-up an extremely specific case completely unrelated to Python, but by the presence of line-breaks in my `python -c "Put ️ code here"` command-line and the way [Meson](https://mesonbuild.com) handle it.